# Difference between "The store is open now" vs "The store is now open"?

Tags: meaning

Is there a difference between the meaning of these two phrases?

*The store is open now.*

*The store is now open.*

Answer (score 1):

To me, a native American English speaker, there is no difference to these phrases.

Comment: To me, 'the store is now open' implies that it was previously closed, but is now open. Whereas the store is open now doesn't have the 'was previously closed' connotation, and to me seems more present? Is this just a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: I agree. The second version is what you would say to declare that it had just opened.